# Drupal 6 Adding comment field in a view list of nodes creates duplicates

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I have a view with the list of nodes and as part of each line returned I would like to show the last comment only per node.

Unfortunately, my view creates multiple copies of each node - one for each comment thats been added

How can I restrict it to one line only for each node with only last comment body added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Googling I found my answer @ http://drupal.org/node/727106#comment-4133208.

However If anybody have better idea, then please post it here for beginners.